# Custom Key for a hashmap doesn't work

Tags: java, hashmap

I've made a custom key class for my hashmap:

```
package com.amit.test;

public class MyCustomKey {
    int customerId;

    public MyCustomKey(int customerId){
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        //return Double.valueOf(Math.random()).intValue() * customerId;
        return customerId;
    }

    public boolean equals(MyCustomKey customKey){
        if(this == customKey)
            return true;
        if(this.getCustomerId() == customKey.getCustomerId())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I then use in the main class as follows:

```
package com.amit.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyCustomHashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<MyCustomKey, String> map = new HashMap<MyCustomKey, String>();
        MyCustomKey customKey1 = new MyCustomKey(1);
        System.out.println("Custom Key 1 hashCode : " + customKey1.hashCode());
        MyCustomKey customKey2 = new MyCustomKey(1);
        System.out.println("Custom Key 2 hashCode : " + customKey2.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Custom Key 1 equals Key 2 : " + customKey1.equals(customKey2));
        System.out.println("Custom Key 1 == Key 2 : " + (customKey1 == customKey2));

        map.put(customKey1, "One");
        map.put(customKey2, "Two");

        Set<MyCustomKey> keys = map.keySet();
        for(MyCustomKey key : keys){
            System.out.println(map.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```

Output::
    I am wondering why I get the output as:

```
Custom Key 1 hashCode : 1
Custom Key 2 hashCode : 1
Custom Key 1 equals Key 2 : true
Custom Key 1 == Key 2 : false
One
Two
```

and not:

```
Custom Key 1 hashCode : 1
Custom Key 2 hashCode : 1
Custom Key 1 equals Key 2 : true
Custom Key 1 == Key 2 : false
One
```

I expect that since my key object contains same int value, and as per the equals method that I've written, it returns me true, then why doesn't it replace the value stored as 'One' with 'Two'.

Comment: I guess I've not overriden the equals method properly. It should accept an Object as parameter and it should somewhat look like                                          public boolean equals(Object customKey){
  if(this == customKey)
   return true;
  if(this.getCustomerId() == ((MyCustomKey)customKey).getCustomerId())
   return true;
  return false;
 }

Comment: It is good practice to use the annotation @Override whenever you override a method. (e.g. hasCode, and equals methods) The compiler will throw an error if your method signature does not match a signature from a super class.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the equals to

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final MyCustomKey other = (MyCustomKey) obj;
    if (this.customerId != other.customerId) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

the output became

```
Custom Key 1 hashCode : 1
Custom Key 2 hashCode : 1
Custom Key 1 equals Key 2 : true
Custom Key 1 == Key 2 : false
Two
```

In the original code, Hashmap was using the default equals implementation, which is provided by the Object class.  This equals uses the address of the object, which would not be equal and lead to two objects being in the map.